# How to change hybrid type list to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a hybird type list:

`A=[0, '0,1', 0, '0,1', '0,1', '0,1', '0,1', 0]`

want to change all to str, but I try

```
for i in A:
  if type(i) == int:
    str(i)
  print(type(i))
```

and get nothing change about those type

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Why not use list comprehension:

`A = [str(x) for x in A]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the type in third line `str(i)` should be `i = str(i)`,

```
A=[0, '0,1', 0, '0,1', '0,1', '0,1', '0,1', 0]

for i in A:
  if type(i) == int:
    i = str(i)
  print(type(i))


# output
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Please note that this wouldn't change the type of original list. For that you need to overwrite the value in the list itself,

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  if type(A[i]) == int:
    A[i] = str(A[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

`chr` is a function that returns a new single character `str`; if you don't assign the result, it's a no-op. So the simplest fix is:

```
for i, x in enumerate(A):  # enumerate to get indices so we can assign back
    if type(x) is int:     # Type checks use is, not == (or use isinstance)
        A[i] = x = chr(x)  # Reassign x as well if you want to use the new value
    print(type(x))
```

That said, it won't make the string `'0'`, it's going to make the string `'\x00'`, because `chr` converts based on raw Unicode ordinals (ASCII ordinals on Py2). If you wanted to produce `'0'`, use `str` instead:

```
for i, x in enumerate(A):  # enumerate to get indices so we can assign back
    if type(x) is int:
        A[i] = x = str(x)
    print(type(x))
```

Comment: just an update, OP modified the question and changed `chr` to `str`